# How to emulate hyper key in Windows 10 using autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm migrating my mac workflow to Windows. One thing I couldn't live without is hyper key which is combination of `Ctrl` + `Option` + `Shift` + `Cmd`. I use **Karabiner** app to remap `Capslock` to this `Hyper` key. I have heard that **Autohotkey** is an *Karabiner alternative for Windows*. Could you guys please help me to emulate this feature in Windows.

My ideal result is:

- Deactivate `Capslock` completely because I rarely use this
- Toggle `Capslock` will perform `ESC` key
- Hold down `Capslock` will perform `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `Windows`. For example `Capslock + C` will be `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Windows+C`

Many thanks in advance!

The following is my attempt with ahk script but it doesn't work at all :(

```
;-----------------------------------------
; hyper key for windows
;=========================================

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; notes
; --------------------------------------------------------------
; ! = alt
; ^ = ctrl
; + = shift
; # = lwin|rwin
;
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#UseHook
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force

SendMode Input

;; deactivate capslock completely
SetCapslockState, AlwaysOff

;; remap capslock to hyper
Capslock::
SendInput {Blind}{Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Shift Down}{LWin Down}
return

Capslock up::
SendInput {Blind}{Ctrl Up}{Alt Up}{Shift Up}{LWin Up}
return

;; vim navigation with hyper
^!+#h:: SendInput {Blind}{Left}
^!+#h up:: SendInput {Blind}{Left Up}
^!+#l:: SendInput {Blind}{Right}
^!+#k:: SendInput {Blind}{Up}
^!+#j:: SendInput {Blind}{Down}

;; popular hotkeys with hyper
^!+#c::^c
^!+#v::^v
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: @PaulR tks for pointing me to that website. I'll post the same question though I thought **Autohotkey script** is also a type of programming language.

Comment: I guess it might be a programming question if you had tried to write an Autohotkey script and it wasn't working, in which case you'd post the non-working script here and ask for help fixing it. But as it stands the question reads more like a general user-level problem, i.e. "how do I do X with software Y ?".

Comment: @PaulR you're right. As I'm reading through Autohotkey docs, hope that I could produce sth by tmr. I'm asking the question in the hope of some Autohotkey guru could give me a quick answer.

Comment: @babygau Your question is too broad. SO is not a code writing service. Present a *specific* problem you're having with code and we can help you solve that problem.

Comment: @2501pls see my updated code snippet, it didn't work when I used all key bindings above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks for anyone trying to help me, I figured out the prob on my own and would like to share it in case anyone comes across this prob.

```
#NoEnv ; recommended for performance and compatibility with future autohotkey releases.
#UseHook
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force

SendMode Input

;; deactivate capslock completely
SetCapslockState, AlwaysOff

;; remap capslock to hyper
;; if capslock is toggled, remap it to esc

;; note: must use tidle prefix to fire hotkey once it is pressed
;; not until the hotkey is released
~Capslock::
    ;; must use downtemp to emulate hyper key, you cannot use down in this case 
    ;; according to https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm, downtemp is as same as down except for ctrl/alt/shift/win keys
    ;; in those cases, downtemp tells subsequent sends that the key is not permanently down, and may be 
    ;; released whenever a keystroke calls for it.
    ;; for example, Send {Ctrl Downtemp} followed later by Send {Left} would produce a normal {Left}
    ;; keystroke, not a Ctrl{Left} keystroke
    Send {Ctrl DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{LWin DownTemp}
    KeyWait, Capslock
    Send {Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}{LWin Up}
    if (A_PriorKey = "Capslock") {
        Send {Esc}
    }
return

;; vim navigation with hyper
~Capslock & h:: Send {Left}
~Capslock & l:: Send {Right}
~Capslock & k:: Send {Up}
~Capslock & j:: Send {Down}

;; popular hotkeys with hyper
~Capslock & c:: Send ^{c}
~Capslock & v:: Send ^{v}
```

Comment: the only answer I found on Capslock hyper on Windows using Autohotkey. Thanks @babygau!!

Comment: INSANE. Thanks a lot! This needs more upvotes. VIM guy here as well so that's a bonus. I use the same combos.

Comment: Also see this for disabling the launch of office for the hyper key: https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app

Answer (score 2):

You can use one attache to Karabiner here:
https://github.com/Vonng/Capslock/blob/master/win/CapsLock.ahk

which maps the same hot keys you are used to using on your Mac

```
;Summary:                                                             |
;o----------------------o---------------------------------------------o
;|CapsLock;             | {ESC}  Especially Convient for vim user     |
;|CaspLock + `          | {CapsLock}CapsLock Switcher as a Substituent|
;|CapsLock + hjklwb     | Vim-Style Cursor Mover                      |
;|CaspLock + uiop       | Convient Home/End PageUp/PageDn             |
;|CaspLock + nm,.       | Convient Delete Controller                  |
;|CapsLock + zxcvay     | Windows-Style Editor                        |
;|CapsLock + Direction  | Mouse Move                                  |
;|CapsLock + Enter      | Mouse Click                                 |
;|CaspLock + {F1}~{F6}  | Media Volume Controller                     |
;|CapsLock + qs         | Windows & Tags Control                      |
;|CapsLock + ;'[]       | Convient Key Mapping                        |
;|CaspLock + dfert      | Frequently Used Programs (Self Defined)     |
;|CaspLock + 123456     | Dev-Hotkey for Visual Studio (Self Defined) |
;|CapsLock + 67890-=    | Shifter as Shift                            |
```

To install it do as follows from [doc](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s12):

1. Right-Click on your desktop.
2. Find "New" in the menu.
3. Click    "AutoHotkey Script" inside the "New" menu.
4. Give the script a new name. It must end with a .ahk extension. For example: `MyScript.ahk`
5. Find the newly created file on your desktop and right-click it.
6. Click    "Edit Script".
7. A window should have popped up, probably Notepad. If    so, SUCCESS!
8. Save the File.
9. Double-click the file/icon in the desktop    to run it. Open notepad or (anything you can type in) and press `Ctrl` and `J`.
10. Hip Hip Hooray! Your first script is done. Go get some reward    snacks then return to reading the rest of this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

An updated version of [@babygau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305817/babygau)'s [script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40435980/6693949) for AutoHotkey v2 that I just finished sorting out, in case it helps anyone :)

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
; recommended for performance and compatibility with future autohotkey releases.
#UseHook
#SingleInstance force

InstallKeybdHook()

SendMode "Input"

;; deactivate capslock completely
SetCapslockState("AlwaysOff")

global CapslockIsDown := false

SetTimer(HandleCapslock, 50)

HandleCapslock() {
    global CapslockIsDown

    if (!CapslockIsDown && GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")) {
        CapslockIsDown := true
        Send("{Ctrl DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{LWin DownTemp}")
    } else if (CapslockIsDown && !GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")) {
        CapslockIsDown := false
        Send("{Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}{LWin Up}")
        if (A_PriorKey == "Capslock") {
            Send("{Esc}")
        }
    }
}

;; vim navigation with hyper
Hotkey "~Capslock & h", SendLeft
Hotkey "~Capslock & l", SendRight
Hotkey "~Capslock & k", SendUp
Hotkey "~Capslock & j", SendDown

SendLeft(ThisHotkey) {
    Send("{Left}")
}

SendRight(ThisHotkey) {
    Send("{Right}")
}

SendUp(ThisHotkey) {
    Send("{Up}")
}

SendDown(ThisHotkey) {
    Send("{Down}")
}

;; popular hotkeys with hyper
Hotkey "~Capslock & c", SendCtrlC
Hotkey "~Capslock & v", SendCtrlV
SendCtrlC(ThisHotkey) {
    Send("^c")
}

SendCtrlV(ThisHotkey) {
    Send("^v")
}
```